# Close SlidingDrawer when user engages outside of SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom sliding drawer that basically has very same traits as a options menu. I wont get into why I'm not using an options menu at this time as its beyond the scope of this question (long story short - it won't work).

The drawer sits on top of a view pager so users can swipe between various fragments to interact with the various aspects of the application. I want to be able to detect when a interacts/engages with anything OUTSIDE OF the SlidingDrawer. If that happens I want to automatically close the sliding drawer.

I've tried listeners, event listeners, gestures, gesture listeners, etc and I cannot seem to get this magic potion to work. Anyone have any ideas/tips/tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
```

This method is inherited from the activity, so you should have access to it.

You didn't post any source code, so I can tell for sure that it'll work. Please try and let us know.

Comment: Ended up writing some logic around touch events to determine the hit area and close the drawer.

Comment: what about if this is a fragment not activity @Udinic

Comment: can you please explain in more detail iam also facing the same issue.